# Why should we up-vote on answers and questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, up-votes

**so here's my theory:**

Besides getting badges, what are our benefits to up-vote?

Everytime we up-vote, we generate reputation which automaticaly lowers our ratio and the ratio effects for example "top xx% of quarter"

Imagine you are talking to someone thinking that way (he/she doesn't up-vote).
How would you convince him/her to "generate reputation" (up-vote, accept, ...)

**I do not think this way! i think up-voting is important**

Comment: You help show the world what are the good questions and helpful answers. What ratio are you caring so deeply about that that has you worried?

Comment: I disagree with the "which automatically lowers our ratio" part. This should not deter anyone from voting.

Comment: calm down! i don't see it that way. it's just a theory. i don't care about ratio. but i sometimes think there are people that do so

Comment: It's not written as theory, @Philipp. It appears as your concrete opinion, which many here don't agree with. (and hence the downvotes)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes... i think that was stupid... i don't agree with it either

Comment: Fair enough, still not sure you're going to get positive feedback but my -1 is taken back.

Comment: @PhilippSander: your question is then unclear. You didn't state that you have a theory, nor do you accurately describe what this ratio is that supposedly has people caring about it.

Comment: You've stated you have a theory, and then asked a question.  A question is not a theory.  A theory is a statement.

Comment: Really, you fear that if you upvote another answer, your arbitrary ranking will lower? Write loads of great answers instead.

Comment: i dont' ..... i understand that you thought this at first, but please read my update! you could also see at my profile on stackoverflow that i up-vote a lot!

Comment: @PhilippSander Yet you don't downvote very much at all.  Why is that?

Comment: His dog got run over by a downvote when he was 4 years old @Servy. Some things never heal.

Comment: because i mostly read interesting questions which i would also ask, there are more good than bad questions and i donw down-vote all questions i don't agreee with

Comment: @PhilippSander "there are more good than bad questions"  I'd disagree with that one.  I see a *lot* more crap than quality content.

Comment: @Servy yes... but does only quality content deserve up-votes and good content doesn't?

Comment: Only quality content deserves upvotes.  I think you might be overestimating the impact of your own votes on your quarterly standings.  Without getting into the math, *you're not that important.*

Comment: Given that this is the foundation of our system it seems like a valuable discussion. However; it does assume a purely selfish model of human nature. While this has elements of truth if it was completely true our species would be long extinct

Comment: There are definitely some people that participate and (presumably) like getting upvotes themselves but don't reciprocate. I find this baffling. If I notice someone doesn't vote much themselves I won't upvote them either.

Comment: Wait, there's a penalty against upvoting? that's news

Comment: @Adel The point he's attempting to make is that by upvoting others you're giving other people more reputation relative to you, thus making your reputation "worth less" due to the inflation that you've caused.

Answer (score 10):

It's your way of providing feedback, thus providing influence to future readers of the question on what the quality of the question/answer is.

Being able to determine, at least to a certain degree, what the community's opinion of a post is can be very valuable for a reader that is unsure of whether a given post is correct/helpful or not.

That's a lot of power to wield.

The effects on reputation (in every way, from all votes) pale in comparison, at least in my eyes.

Answer (score 10):

Without voting, all content would seem equally good or bad. There would be no immediate difference, and all we'd have is a grey blob of text for users to swim around in.

With votes however (for the most part) users can easily identify what is good content, and what is best left ignored or might not be all that valuable. Admittedly, that's the ideal scenario, but you get the point.

So vote.

Comment: Luckily we're not a forum then @AlienArrays ;)

Answer (score 5):

You are probably correct, this is probably a ["tragedy of the commons"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) situation where it is in everyone’s individual best interests to destroy the system, but if everyone followed their pure best interests the system would be destroyed and there would be nothing for anyone. Thankfully this doesn't actually occur for the following reasons:

- Community spirit trumps selfish self interest and people vote based on quality not on their own self interests.
- There are a lot of questions so your given upvotes barely reduce your ranking at all.
- Reputation has no value outside the system so only people who believe in the system will be effected by this --> point 1.
- You do get "something" in that you get to show your own opinion as to the correct way to do something. Making the world you live in that little bit better.